# selenium click method does not work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click a button by its class name. The method works fine except that when the button is not shown in the main page. I mean some times I have to click '`load more`' first and then the button appears. In the last case, I can find the element by its class name however the click method does not work.

```
try:
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_class_name("search-result-title")
    inputElement.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("load-more-search-results")
    inputElement.click()
    # driver.refresh()


sleep(5)
inputElement2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("search-result-title")
inputElement2.click()
```

Note: The '`load more`' button does not reload the page it just shows more content in the same page.

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? What are the symptoms? Also, is it possible for you to share the URL of the page you are working with?

Comment: https://isbndb.com/search/books/195153448

This is an example of the page. I need to click the 'load more' button which works fine by using element.click() method. And then I need to click the links that appear. I can find the button element of the loaded data but when I use the click method it does nothing